# How to update the text of menu in android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**What i have**::

*I have a menu in actionbar it has two sub-items in it*

---

**buffet_map_cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="cart">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_cart_buy"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
                android:title="Sort by newest"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_cart_reserve"
                android:icon="@drawable/button_reserve_selector"
                android:title="Sort by rating"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

---

**What i am trying to do**::

- I want to update the text dynamically for the menu buttons
  `action_cart_buy` and `action_cart_reserve`
- How to find this resource from the Java code and update the text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the `Menu` object in `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu` (better).

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart_buy);
    item.setTitle("Any title");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

To make the UI update your ActionBar at the right time, you have to call:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) for dynamic updates:

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

You can use it like:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem buyItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart_buy);
    MenuItem reserveItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart_reserve);
    buyItem.setTitle("New buyItem String");
    reserveItem.setTitle("New reserveItem String");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [findItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29) from Menu and than [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html), there is a [setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Edit--
There is a topic called "Changing menu items at runtime" in this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) which may help you as well.

Comment: Which method should i need to do this onprepareoptions menu or any other ?